# How to have Person Account Records as Related list on its Business Account

Tags: related-list, person-accounts

I have a Business Account and there are multiple Person Accounts associated to this person account, I want to display all these person accounts as related list on the Business Account Record.

I have tried using Dynamic Related list and also tried list view but nothing seems to work.

Please tell me how can I achieve this or is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Describe the relationship between a business account and a few person accounts and give us an example with a few records. Then I can recommend some options. Do you already have a relationship established by a lookup field or some other means? or are you asking for advice on how to link the two types of records?

Comment: Please pose your questions on the comment section of the question and not as an Answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/199399)